# Avg of multiple columns in project operator

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

We have 2 customlogs in loganalytics out of that I am able to get avg of each one and I need to merge those 2 and make it as 1 means avg of vpn+url

```
workspace(name).vpn_CL
| extend healty=iff(Status_s == 'Connected' , 100 , 0)
| summarize vpn = avg(healty) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
| 
join
(
    workspace(name).url_CL
    | extend Availability=iff(StatusDescription_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
    | summarize URL=avg(Availability) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
 ) on ClientName_s
  | project Client=ClientName_s, Environment=EnvName_s , vpn , URL
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/0BNYWW4 .....i want another column saying avag of URL + VPN

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think the value of the average of `vpn+url` is the result of plus `vpn` value with `url` value when the number of `healty` entites is equals to the number of `Availability` entites.

[image]

Otherwise, if their entites quantity are not equal, the average of the two labels is a expected value based on their probabilities,

[image]

Then,

```
workspace(name).vpn_CL
| extend healty=iff(Status_s == 'Connected' , 100 , 0)
| summarize m = count(), vpn = avg(healty) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
| 
join
(
    workspace(name).url_CL
    | extend Availability=iff(StatusDescription_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
    | summarize n = count(), URL=avg(Availability) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
 ) on ClientName_s
  | project Client=ClientName_s, Environment=EnvName_s , vpn , URL, avgOfVpnUrl = vpn*m/(m+n)+url*n/(m+n)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..by executing your query getting avarage as attached link 
   https://ibb.co/vJxd3sj

Comment: workspace(name).vpnclient_CL
| where ClientName_s == "xxxx"
| extend healty=iff(Status_s == 'Connected' , 100 , 0)
| summarize vpn = avg(healty) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
| 
join
(
    workspace(name).url_json_CL
 | extend Availability=iff(StatusDescription_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
 | summarize URL=avg(Availability) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
 ) on ClientName_s
 | extend finalstatus=(vpn+URL)/2
 | project Client=ClientName_s, Environment=EnvName_s , vpn , URL ,finalstatus

Comment: I have changed as above which giving exact result

Comment: @DevReddy If my answer helps, could you mark it? Thanks.